# New item in your Stack Exchange inbox wrong date

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, global-inbox

The date that I last checked my inbox seems wrong, I check my inbox daily while the email specifies that I last checked it on 2015-05-18.

[image]

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271619/stack-exchange-doesnt-know-when-i-last-checked-my-global-inbox).

Comment: Also exactly `2015-05-18` for me.

Comment: Well, it's for all sites, so better suited for MSE. (nothing wrong having it here too though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic for updating that date was broken by inbox changes in May 2015, which is why many users see "last checked" dates around then. It had been fixed, and will now update appropriately whenever you open [the inbox in the top bar](/topbar/inbox) or [view it on StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox).